# Fabric cd() with ssh agent

Tags: python, ssh, fabric

How to implement custom cd() that use ssh agent in Fabric?

In my deployment script, i packaged run(), sudo(), put() like above to implement ssh agent:

```
from fabric.api import run, sudo, cd

PREFIX = "ssh user@remote:5044 '"

def custom_run(cmd):
    new_cmd = PREFIX + cmd + "'"
    run(new_cmd)

def custom_sudo(cmd):
    new_cmd = PREFIX + cmd + "'"
    sudo(new_cmd)
```

But as i known, to manage context, Fabric's cd() changed global varible env.cwd

not like run or sudo, execute some command directly.

So, is there any approach to implement cd() with ssh agent?

```
$ ssh usr@1st-host "ssh usr@2nd-host 'cd pwd;cmd...'"
```

Comment: Fabric will cd to the directory in env.cwd before executing the commands, so I don't understand what problem you are trying to solve.

Comment: Please explain what problem you are trying to solve. It seems to me you are trying to reimplement fabric in fabric, which makes no sense.

Comment: sorry about my mistake! PREFIX is  `"ssh user@remote:5044 '"` not `user@remote:5044`, so my problem is that how to reimplement fabric cd() to enter 3rd host's directory by ssh and excute command, not the target host that env.host specified.

Comment: No that is not your problem, that's what you are trying to do to solve the problem you actually have. Please explain the problem you are trying to solve.

Comment: You probably want to have a look at http://docs.fabfile.org/en/latest/usage/env.html#gateway and use that rather than rolling your own

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to use the `--user` flag in `fab`, and not `PREFIX`.

For example: `fab --user=myself abc` runs command `abc` as user `myself`.

For `cd`, have a look at http://docs.fabfile.org/en/1.6/api/core/context_managers.html?highlight=cd#fabric.context_managers.cd